# Prove that the space of contraction mappings in $[0,1]$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, contraction-mapping

I'm going through James Dugundji's *Topology* but I'm having trouble with chapter XI, section 4 problem 2:

> 2. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of all continuous maps $I\to I$ such that $|f(s)-f(t)|\leq |s-t|$. Define
>    $$d^+(f,g)=\max_{0\leq t \leq 1}|f(t)-g(t)|.$$
>    Prove: $\mathscr{F}$ is compact.

Here $I=[0,1]$. I'm familiar with the main properties of compactness and know that $1°$ countable paracompact spaces are compact iff every sequence has convergent subsequence. I was trying to use this on $\mathscr{F}$ but had no success.

I'm looking for any *hints* on how to start this proof.

Edit: I'm attempting an elementary proof, Arzela-Ascoli comes after this chapter so it shouldn't be used. Function spaces and completeness hasn't been touched on yet (I guess completeness in $I$ should be available though).

Comment: Perhaps Arzela-Ascoli might help here?

Comment: That comes in the next chapter of the book. I'm trying to solve it only with the material presented prior to this problem: basically an elementary proof.

Comment: @legionwhale do you mean the sequence of functions $f_n$ each defined by $x\mapsto n$? The thing is that $f_n$ ought be from $I$ to $I$ so this sequence is not on $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: @SebastiánP.Pincheira Ah, I missed that. My mistake.

Comment: Hmm maybe you shouldn't use Arzela-Ascoli directly but you could try to copy the argument; the argument itself is just a standard diagonalization.

Comment: Your discussion of what you can use and cannot leaves me a little unclear about what is available with respect to conpleteness. Have you covered that a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded? Completeness can proven from completeness of the unit interval. And the contraction condition gives a fairly simple way of showing total-boundedness. In fact, this approach is probably a good way to prove the result even if you just rely directly on completeness on $I$ without reference to the function space.